# Trove API Search All

Tags: jquery, api

I'm trying to get a Trove API working on a website that searches for everything on Trove and displays one result based on what the user has put into the search bar. I am very new to this and i have written some code to search all but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my Javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var storedData = new Array();

        function logAllUrls() {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * storedData.length);
            console.log(storedData[index]);
            storedData = new Array();
        }

        var key = "my key";    

        $("#form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var query = "&q=" + $('#input').val();
            var url = "http://api.trove.nla.gov.au/result?key=";
            var zone = "&zone=all";
            var n = "&n=5";
            var encoding = "&encoding=json";

            url += key + zone + n + encoding + query; 

            $.getJSON(url, response);
        });
    });
```

I have it linked to a form on a HTML page.

Whenever i type in a search term and click search i get this response in the chrome console,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined(anonymous function) 
(anonymous function)    @   api.js:30
n.event.dispatch    @   jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
n.event.add.r.handle    @   jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
```

These are the links i have in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="api.js"></script>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You are currently not defining what to do with the data loaded via the API (you’re passing a callback function called `response` in the last line without defining it anywhere). What would you like to do with the API response?

Comment: Where is the `response` function?

Comment: I think your main problem, based on your code sample, is that... `response` is `not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, the getJSON call takes a function for when the data is successfully returned from the server.

The Trove servers, however, are on another domain so you'll have to use JSONP by including "callback=?" somewhere in your URL.

Or you could just use the library at: https://github.com/chrrrisw/trove-js to abstract all this away.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.